# latex errors about bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\author{soham}
\begin{document}
\title{Fist Document}
\maketitle
This is my first document & I like editing in LaTeX \cite{abc}.
\begin{enumerate}
\itemHello
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{fig1a.png}
\end{figure}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem {ab}
Holland, J.H., Adaptation in Natural and Artificial Systems. University of Michigan Press, 1975.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Care to share with us which error messages you got. Besides, that & at the 6th line will produce an error message (which has nothing to do with the bibliography).

Comment: Your code has a problem in `document & I like`. You can not use `&` like that. Use `\&` instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors in your code. I corrected them (marked the important changes with `<==========`) in the following MWE. To be able to use command `\includegraphics` you have to load/call package `graphicx`. I corrected some typhos too.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx} % <===============================================

\author{soham}


\begin{document}

\title{First Document}
\maketitle
This is my first document \& I like editing in LaTeX \cite{ab}. % <=====
\begin{enumerate}
\item Hello % <=========================================================
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image} % <==========================
\end{figure}
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem {ab}
Holland, J.H., Adaptation in Natural and Artificial Systems. University of Michigan Press, 1975.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

compiles without errors to

[image: resulting pdf]